# Show that there is one person who knows everybody.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

There are $n$ people. For every pair of them there is exactly one person who knows both. I need to show that there is one person who knows everybody.

I need a hint to solve this problem.

Comment: Did you try induction over $n$ ? Another idea might be the pigeonhole pinciple.

Comment: Peter, as far as I know, neither of those approaches lead to a solution. Are you just throwing out possible things to consider?

Comment: @CalvinLin In fact, I am guessing what could lead to a solution. Sure that my ideas actually do not work ?

Comment: @Peter Reasonably so. IIRC, the solution set is only when $n$ is odd, and we have several triangles hinged at a point.

Comment: HAve you tried Reductium ad absurdum? Assume that for any person, there is at least one other that is unkown for him/her

Comment: Duplicate of [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1078743/suppose-n-people-are-in-a-party-and-every-two-of-them-have-exactly-one-common?rq=1). (I selected the wrong one, so can't vote to close.)

Answer (score 0):

This result is called the friendship theorem.

**Hint :** In the proof I know you need to claim that it's false and let G, a friendship graph, have $ \Delta < n-1 $. After you show that $G$ is regular using two non-adjacent vertices and graph eigenvalues.